# No inclusion between that of $L^\infty$ and $L^p$.

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function that is in $L^p$ but not in $L^\infty$ when the measure of our underlying set is infinite?

For the finite case this is simple, let $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ with domain $(0,1)$. Clearly we are integrable, but not essentially bounded.

Is there a simple function for the infinite case?

Comment: What about constant functions?

Comment: Clayton's example of constant functions answers the question you ask in the body of the post, but that means the title is incorrect since $L^\infty$ isn't a subset of $L^p$, let alone a proper one.

Comment: @Clayton: Thank you for your answer, I typed my question incorrectly I apologize.

Comment: @FrancisAdams: Thank you for your comment, I fixed the title and question much apologies.

Comment: What about just taking $(0,\infty)$ with the Lebesgue measure, and consider $f$ given by $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+x^2}$? This is in $L^1$, but not essentially bounded.